# Is there a way to assign a member depending on which derived class has been created?

Tags: c++, constructor

I think I'm overlooking the super obvious, but I just want it so that if I create a Shape it has the name "Unique" and if I create a Cube it has the name "Cube", without having to re-set it in the derived class.

```
class Shape
{public:
    Shape() : type("Unique") {}
    std::string type;
};


class Sphere : public Shape
{public:
    Sphere() : Shape() { 
        //type= "Sphere";
    }
};

class Cube : public Shape
{public:
    Cube() : Shape() {
        // type = "Cube"
    }

};

int main()
{
     Shape s; // Has name "Unique"
     Cube c; // Has name "Cube"
}
```

Comment: `Shape(std::string type = "Unique") : type(type) {}`. `Cube() : Shape("Cube") {}`? I mean it has to get the string from somewhere,  and reflection is not in C++ yet.

Comment: @JHBonarius I was thinking `typeid` before I remembered that `typeid` has a different behavior in base class constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an optional parameter to your `Shape` constructor

```
class Shape
{public:
    Shape(const std::string& t = "Unique") : type(t) {}
    std::string type;
};


class Sphere : public Shape
{public:
    Sphere() : Shape("Sphere") { 
    }
};

class Cube : public Shape
{public:
    Cube() : Shape("Cube") {
    }

};
```